# Craft CMS throws Internal Server Error 500

Tags: craft3, installation

I got given a Craft CMS project build with composer and npm. Pointed valet to the correct folder, installed all the dependencies and started the app with `npm run watch`.

http://localhost:3000 just gives me an "Internal Server Error" though...

[image: Craft CMS Internal Server Error]

There is nothing in the logs apart from sth inside storage/logs/web.log which does not sound like a showstopper:

`2020-12-07 06:59:06 [-][-][-][error][yii\base\ErrorException:8192] yii\base\ErrorException: Method ReflectionParameter::isArray() is deprecated in /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php:133 Stack trace:`

Error 500 bugs are really hard to track down, any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message and this: https://php.watch/versions/8.0/deprecated-reflectionparameter-methods, it sounds like you're running PHP 8, which Craft isn't compatible with, yet.

The soon-to-be-released Craft 3.6 adds PHP 8 compatibility, so you'll want to downgrade to PHP 7.4 until that's out.

Comment: thank you so much for the hint with the PHP versions, downgrading to PHP 7.4 was the solution :)